# Websites rich with exercices or explanation for SML?

Tags: sml, smlnj, ml

I know that I need to pass through google to search etc, I did but they don't offer what I need 90% of this sites give the same example and even sometimes the same explanation, If there someone who have for example links from university or school or may be in his dropbox, I will be very thankfull.

Comment: Can you tell us what you have found so far and what you need to know that's not covered in those resources?

Comment: I need exercices, explanation with details for example , some code where I can improve my knowloedge

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately it seems that the best resources for learning Standard ML are various paper books (e.g. [Introduction to Programming using SML](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201398206) by Hansen & Rischel, [ML for the Working Programmer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/052156543X) by Larry C. Paulson, or [Programming in Standard ML](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/introsml/) by Robert Harper (the last one is available for free online), as well as resource material from various university courses of which none I have encountered excels.

Here is [a number of exam assignments](http://sshine.github.io/standardml-exercises.html) from one course using Standard ML:

Answer (score 3):

I took the [Programming Languages Course](https://www.coursera.org/course/proglang) at Coursera and it was superb. Most of the course is based on SML.

The first first four weeks are entirely about SML. The material distributed in the course is great and every week there are plenty of interesting exercises to solve.

The good news is that this course is about to start in October 3, 2013 again. So this is your opportunity.

I own the list of books mentioned in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18235726/697630). They all are very good. But I also own another one not mentioned above and that I considered great for initial ML learning: [Elements of ML Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0137903871) by Jeffrey Ulman. In fact I preferred this to the others mentioned above because I found its explanations simpler and the exercises more progressively challenging.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the book Programming in Standard ML by Colin Meyers,Chris Clark,Ellen Poon
and ML for the working Programmer by L C Paulson.The former is really a great book as it always puts types in function declarations..this way you will master the underlying types in sml